# Must Generate same token unless it expired

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

As default in `spring authorization server` it generate unique token each request.
But the requirement is to generate `same token` if the previous token is still not expired, and if expired must generate new token.
Is this even possible?

```
 RegisteredClient
                .withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder()
                        .tokenEndpointAuthenticationSigningAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256)
                        .build())
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder()
                        .accessTokenFormat(OAuth2TokenFormat.SELF_CONTAINED)
                        .idTokenSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256)
                        .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
                        .build())
                .scope("read")
                .build();
```

```
public OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService() {
        return  new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizationService();
    }
```